# In an Altera project, how to I use get_registers to obtain registers from only one level or hierarchy

Tags: constraints, fpga, intel-fpga

I have small problem with my Altera constraints.

I would like to use `get_registers` to get all registers from a specific hierarchy level.

For example if the hierarchy is as follows:

```
+-A:a_inst
| +-B:b_inst
| | +-C:c_inst
```

`get_registers {A:a_inst|B:*}` will give me all registers under B including those in C.

My current solution is as follows

```
set all_b_regs [get_registers {A:a_inst|B:*}] #This includes registers in C as well
set all_sub_regs [get_registers {A:a_inst|B:*|*:*}]
set only_b_regs [remove_from_collection $all_b_regs $all_sub_regs]
```

I was wondering if anyone knew of any better way of doing this with a single command.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `-hierarchical` option

```
get_registers -hierarchical a_inst|*
```

See http://www.altera.com/literature/hb/qts/qts_qii53018.pdf (Table 7-3)